# Get Dynamic Class Names in List Element with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-lists

I want to identify order steps on a website...

Through the 5 five steps, the url is not changing... only the tabs class names are changing through the process.

Tabs class name on step 1 :

```
<ul class="step clearfix" id="order_step">

<li class="step_current first"> <span>Recap</span></li>
<li class="step_todo second"> <span> Connexion</span></li>
<li class="step_todo third"> <span> Address</span></li>
<li class="step_todo four"> <span> Delivery</span></li>
<li id="step_end" class="step_todo last"> <span> Paiement</span></li>

</ul>
```

Tabs class name on step 2:

```
<ul class="step clearfix" id="order_step">

<li class="step_done first"> <span>Recap</span></li>
<li class="step_current second"> <span> Connexion</span></li>
<li class="step_todo third"> <span> Address</span></li>
<li class="step_todo four"> <span> Delivery</span></li>
<li id="step_end" class="step_todo last"> <span> Paiement</span></li>

</ul>
```

How to use JQuery to get the class name matching "step_current" ?

Comment: show your desired output it would be very easy to figure what are you trying to achieve

Comment: `$(".step_current").attr("class")`?

Comment: This is working... and you help me find the right code for my goal : ```$("li.step_current")[0].textContent```

Answer (score 0):

Here what I was looking for (I'm not a JS expert so I was mixing up operators) :

`$("li.step_current")[0].textContent`

So I can retrieve the title of the active tab.

Thanks for the helpful comments.